# How to execute a stored procedure with 109 parameters?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am a novice trying to execute, "exec dbo.UpdateDestinationTable ?,?,?,?,?", stored procedure that can take 109 parameters.

EDIT:
I am trying to Insert and Update Records with an SSIS ETL Package

Comment: Perhaps asking you to call an SP with 109 parameters is your senior's idea of having some fun?

Comment: It's pretty much the same as executing a SP with 1 parameter.   Only there's 108 more.

Comment: That sounds like a table with too many columns. :)

Comment: Might be easier for you to throw the column list into a spreadsheet and build the SQL exec statement via concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to:

```
exec dbo.UpdateDestinationTable Param1, Param2, Param3, etc
```

All the way to 109. As the one comment mentioned sounds a little ridiculous. Could you provide more detail on the update taking place then we might be able to provide a better solution.

Comment: im trying to Insert and Update Records with an SSIS ETL Package